# Utorrent 3.4.2 does not download with max download rate (8-9Mb)

Tags: windows-8, download, utorrent

I have a 100Mb internet connection.

I used to have windows 8.1 installed and I used uTorrent. Download speeds were about 6-8MB/sec.
I now have windows 8 installen and the download speed has dropped to about 1.5 Mb.

I tried every utorrent post and issue solver on youtube, but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: Most ISPs will use DPI and throttle torrent traffic.

Comment: Did you do a clean installation of windows 8?  Did you use (paste sense) to have a good share of uploaded files and do you now have none/little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you connect to the same port as specified on your router. uTorrent will by default select a random port. You need to set this portmapping correct, otherwise it will only use uPNP port mappings which means you get only a fraction of your capable bandwidth.

Comment: Well i dont know my router port and on the router there is non

Comment: @Alex - Please provide more information about your home network.  Because you have to have either a router and modem or you have a modem with multiple lan ports.

Comment: i have a Hotbox (router + cabled modem) i use only the modem mode..and not the Wifi that i also have

Comment: @Alex, so you need to go to the modem's settings page, NAT, Port forwarding, and setup a port to your pc, then configure uTorrent to use that specific port.

Comment: Hmm did that...it shows me the IP but no port..there is several port indication like FTP and HTTP and so one..but i dont know with one to set at utorrent...strange that my speed is not like before (Btw:i play BF4 and the ping on euro servers is 50 +-)